# how to enter further commands to cmd after "dotnet app.dll" command

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cmd, command-line

I run my application from cmd using dotnet command but after application started, I cant use cmd window. It does not allow me to type further commands. It sits the state shown below.

How can i prevent this?

Also as a second question, when I closed this cmd window, my dotnet application stops. How can I also prevent this?

[image]

Comment: yeeeah... the cmd is your application now... so if you close it down, it shuts off. It also says "Ctrl+C to shutdown". It is maybe easier to understand if you think of your cmd as a browser that is only able to communicate with one website at a time. You wouldn't expect netflix to keep playing your video after closing the browser. 
What "it sounds like you want to do"; Is to create a Windows Service instead, this will run in the background and not of your cmd.

Comment: That's how terminals and shells work in all OSs. You started an application from a terminal so now the application's output is shown in the terminal. Anything you type is sent to the application's standard input. All command-line utilities behave the same. If you type `ping -t ....` for example, you'll only see `ping`'s output. Anything you type will be sent to the `ping` process.

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? How to run an ASP.NET web app as a service? This has nothing to do with terminals. To understand how terminals and shells work, check [Windows Command Line Backgrounder](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-backgrounder/). The concepts are the same for Linux. This article and the ones that follow explain what is actually going on

Comment: Windows Terminal is a vastly better CLI host than `cmd.exe` natively launches. Multiple tabs, multiple panes per tab... You cannot do anything about `dotnet watch` etc. occupying a command line session, so the answer is to have multiple sessions.